# Induced emf in a rotating disc

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, voltage, conductors

A question in my book was given as

> A conducting disc of radius R rotates about its axis with an angular velocity $\omega$. Then the potential difference between centre of mass of disc and its edge is (no magnetic field is present)

The answer stated that:

1. There will be a potential difference present
2. The value of which was obtained by using $eE = m\omega^2r$ (not sure why this holds true) for an electron $e$ in the disc and then obtaining the electric field and finding the potential difference by integration -$E.dr$

**My question:** While deriving the motional emf in a rotating disc in magnetic field, we consider only the flux change (or say the $(v\times B).dl$) responsible for the induced emf given as $\frac{1}{2}B\omega r^2$. Why do we not consider the emf obtained due to the above phenomenon aswell since it happens even in the absence of magnetic field?

**Extra but related question:** Why does $eE = m\omega^2r$ hold true for an electron in a conducting disc? What stops it from moving radially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both these questions have been asked (and answered) within the last 3 or 4 weeks on this site. The gist of the answer to your main question is that the 'centrifugal emf' is very much smaller than the 'magnetic emf'. *You should show this for yourself by putting figures into your formulae*. [Note that a magnetic field of 1 T would be a very strong field.]

To answer your extra question: the free electrons *do* move outwards at first, as there is no force to provide them with a centripetal acceleration. But as they move outward they create a charge separation: negative to the outside of the disc; positive to the inside. These charges create an electric field, $E$, that *does* provide the required centripetal acceleration. Hence the equation that you've quoted: $=^2$.